# ASP.NET Core Web API : slow loading of images

Tags: api, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have an API `GET` method that returns images:

```
[HttpGet("images/{imageNo:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImageAsync(int imageNo)
{
     var path = $"C:\\image_{imageNo}";
     var data = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);

     return File(data, "image/jpeg");
}
```

And in my Blazor Server app, all images from the local drive load very slowly:

[image: image load]

Am I doing something wrong or is it really normal time to load images from local drive?

Comment: Do you need to control the access of each image separately? You don't seem to be doing anything and simply returns the image. Why don't you store them in the `wwwroot` folder for free access for users.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine wwwroot is not an option, I realy need to read from the local disk

Comment: how can the download speed of wwroot or from a local disk be so different?

Comment: Are you using [Stream image data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-image-data)? Have you tried placing the image under wwwroot to compare the speed? This seems to be a normal rate. In addition, too many images on a website will also affect the loading rate.

Comment: @Chen the difference in download speed from the local disk and wwwroot is very large (10 times). no I don't use stream image data, I want it to be a web api method

Comment: Using stream image data also gets the corresponding image from Api. As you can see in [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-7.0#stream-image-data): `await Http.GetStreamAsync("Your Api");` You can have a try.

Comment: @Chen, what is the advantage to use stream image data?